# Loop back observable in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

This is a bit of a convoluted example, but I was wondering how to do the following in RxJs: After a certain part in the pipeline, feed the value back into an earlier part of the pipeline, so it will get processed again.

```js
of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).pipe(
  map(x => x + 1),
  map(x => x + 1),
  filter(x => x % 2),
  // refeed after the first map but before the second
)
```

Comment: Maybe you have a look at the [expand](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/expand) operator; it enables kind of a 'refeed'. What is the result you expect in your example above?

Comment: or you could use a recursive function that returns an observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you might use expand to do this:

```ts
function isEven(x) {
  return x % 2 == 0
}

of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).pipe(
  map(x => x + 1),
  expand(x => of(x).pipe(
    map(x => x + 1),
    filter(isEven)
  ))
);
```

Here's how you might write a recursive function to do this:

```ts
function isEven(x) {
  return x % 2 == 0
}

function loopBack(x : number) {
  return of(x).pipe(
    map(x => x + 1),
    filter(isEven),
    mergeMap(loopBack),
    startWith(x)
  );
}

of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).pipe(
  map(x => x + 1),
  mergeMap(loopBack),
);
```